# Start stop resume a thread C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on an example for making a thread start and stop and continue after stopping.

I wrote code for starting, but I don't know how to stop the thread. If anyone knows how, please show me where to edit my code.

```
private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //START BG WORKER
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    Thread thr = new Thread(Start);
    thr.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thr.Start();
}
static void Start()
{
    var dr = new ChromeDriver();
    dr.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
    dr.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
}
private void cancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
private void contiBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use Threads, use Tasks instead.  And when you need to start/stop them, you already did something wrong.

Comment: This question is not about threads but simply about managing a resource with local variables vs object fields.

Comment: is there any tutorial about to use tasks instead of threads ?

Comment: Yes, very many. Ask google.